# Jquery cart quantity update button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The basket is automatically updated in these codes. The basket is automatically updated when the number of products changes.
However, I want it to be updated when the button is clicked.
I've tried jquery "click" but failed.
Running codes are below.

How to do it?

```js
/* Set rates + misc */
var taxRate = 0.05;
var shippingRate = 15.00; 
var fadeTime = 300;


/* Assign actions */
$('.product-quantity input').change( function() {
  updateQuantity(this);
});

$('.product-removal button').click( function() {
  removeItem(this);
});


/* Recalculate cart */
function recalculateCart()
{
  var subtotal = 0;
  
  /* Sum up row totals */
  $('.product').each(function () {
    subtotal += parseFloat($(this).children('.product-line-price').text());
  });
  
  /* Calculate totals */
  var tax = subtotal * taxRate;
  var shipping = (subtotal > 0 ? shippingRate : 0);
  var total = subtotal + tax + shipping;
  
  /* Update totals display */
  $('.totals-value').fadeOut(fadeTime, function() {
    $('#cart-subtotal').html(subtotal.toFixed(2));
    $('#cart-tax').html(tax.toFixed(2));
    $('#cart-shipping').html(shipping.toFixed(2));
    $('#cart-total').html(total.toFixed(2));
    if(total == 0){
      $('.checkout').fadeOut(fadeTime);
    }else{
      $('.checkout').fadeIn(fadeTime);
    }
    $('.totals-value').fadeIn(fadeTime);
  });
}


/* Update quantity */
function updateQuantity(quantityInput)
{
  /* Calculate line price */
  var productRow = $(quantityInput).parent().parent();
  var price = parseFloat(productRow.children('.product-price').text());
  var quantity = $(quantityInput).val();
  var linePrice = price * quantity;
  
  /* Update line price display and recalc cart totals */
  productRow.children('.product-line-price').each(function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(fadeTime, function() {
      $(this).text(linePrice.toFixed(2));
      recalculateCart();
      $(this).fadeIn(fadeTime);
    });
  });  
}


/* Remove item from cart */
function removeItem(removeButton)
{
  /* Remove row from DOM and recalc cart total */
  var productRow = $(removeButton).parent().parent();
  productRow.slideUp(fadeTime, function() {
    productRow.remove();
    recalculateCart();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Shopping Cart</h1>

<div class="shopping-cart">

  <div class="column-labels">
    <label class="product-image">Image</label>
    <label class="product-details">Product</label>
    <label class="product-price">Price</label>
    <label class="product-quantity">Quantity</label>
    <label class="product-removal">Remove</label>
    <label class="product-line-price">Total</label>
  </div>

  <div class="product">
    <div class="product-image">
     
    </div>
    <div class="product-details">
      <div class="product-title">Dingo Dog Bones</div>
      <p class="product-description">The best dog bones of all time. Holy crap. Your dog will be begging for these things! I got curious once and ate one myself. I'm a fan.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product-price">12.99</div>
    <div class="product-quantity">
      <input type="number" value="2" min="1">
    </div>
    <div class="product-removal">
      <button class="remove-product">
        Remove
      </button>
<button class="update-quantity-product">
        Update
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="product-line-price">25.98</div>
  </div>



  <div class="totals">
    <div class="totals-item">
      <label>Subtotal</label>
      <div class="totals-value" id="cart-subtotal">71.97</div>
    </div>
    <div class="totals-item">
      <label>Tax (5%)</label>
      <div class="totals-value" id="cart-tax">3.60</div>
    </div>
    <div class="totals-item">
      <label>Shipping</label>
      <div class="totals-value" id="cart-shipping">15.00</div>
    </div>
    <div class="totals-item totals-item-total">
      <label>Grand Total</label>
      <div class="totals-value" id="cart-total">90.57</div>
    </div>
  </div>
      
      <button class="checkout">Checkout</button>

</div>
```

The basket is automatically updated in these codes. The basket is automatically updated when the number of products changes.
However, I want it to be updated when the button is clicked.
I've tried jquery "click" but failed.
Running codes are below.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code, you have used many class with same name, so it was removing the items, sse my answer.

```js
/* Set rates + misc */
var taxRate = 0.05;
var shippingRate = 15.00; 
var fadeTime = 300;


/* Assign actions */
//$('.product-quantity input').change( function() {
  //updateQuantity(this);
//});

$(document).on('click', '.update-quantity-product', function(e){

  var vals =  $('input').val();
 // alert(vals);
   updateQuantity(vals, $('input'));
})

$('.remove-product-btn').click( function() {
  removeItem(this);
});


/* Recalculate cart */
function recalculateCart()
{
  var subtotal = 0;
  
  /* Sum up row totals */
  $('.product').each(function () {
    subtotal += parseFloat($(this).children('.product-line-price').text());
  });
  
  /* Calculate totals */
  var tax = subtotal * taxRate;
  var shipping = (subtotal > 0 ? shippingRate : 0);
  var total = subtotal + tax + shipping;
  
  /* Update totals display */
  $('.totals-value').fadeOut(fadeTime, function() {
    $('#cart-subtotal').html(subtotal.toFixed(2));
    $('#cart-tax').html(tax.toFixed(2));
    $('#cart-shipping').html(shipping.toFixed(2));
    $('#cart-total').html(total.toFixed(2));
    if(total == 0){
      $('.checkout').fadeOut(fadeTime);
    }else{
      $('.checkout').fadeIn(fadeTime);
    }
    $('.totals-value').fadeIn(fadeTime);
  });
}


/* Update quantity */
function updateQuantity(qty, quantityInput)
{
  /* Calculate line price */
  var productRow = $(quantityInput).parent().parent();
  var price = parseFloat(productRow.children('.product-price').text());
  var quantity = $(quantityInput).val();
  var linePrice = price * quantity;
  
  /* Update line price display and recalc cart totals */
  productRow.children('.product-line-price').each(function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(fadeTime, function() {
      $(this).text(linePrice.toFixed(2));
      recalculateCart();
      $(this).fadeIn(fadeTime);
    });
  });  
}


/* Remove item from cart */
function removeItem(removeButton)
{
  /* Remove row from DOM and recalc cart total */
  var productRow = $(removeButton).parent().parent();
  productRow.slideUp(fadeTime, function() {
    productRow.remove();
    recalculateCart();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Shopping Cart</h1>

<div class="shopping-cart">

  <div class="column-labels">
    <label class="product-image">Image</label>
    <label class="product-details">Product</label>
    <label class="product-price">Price</label>
    <label class="product-quantity">Quantity</label>
    <label class="product-removal">Remove</label>
    <label class="product-line-price">Total</label>
  </div>

  <div class="product">
    <div class="product-image">
     
    </div>
    <div class="product-details">
      <div class="product-title">Dingo Dog Bones</div>
      <p class="product-description">The best dog bones of all time. Holy crap. Your dog will be begging for these things! I got curious once and ate one myself. I'm a fan.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product-price">12.99</div>
    <div class="product-quantity">
      <input type="number" value="2" min="1">
    </div>
    <div class="product-removal">
      <button class="remove-product-btn">
        Remove
      </button>
<button class="update-quantity-product" type="button">
        Update
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="product-line-price">25.98</div>
  </div>



  <div class="totals">
    <div class="totals-item">
      <label>Subtotal</label>
      <div class="totals-value" id="cart-subtotal">71.97</div>
    </div>
    <div class="totals-item">
      <label>Tax (5%)</label>
      <div class="totals-value" id="cart-tax">3.60</div>
    </div>
    <div class="totals-item">
      <label>Shipping</label>
      <div class="totals-value" id="cart-shipping">15.00</div>
    </div>
    <div class="totals-item totals-item-total">
      <label>Grand Total</label>
      <div class="totals-value" id="cart-total">90.57</div>
    </div>
  </div>
      
      <button class="checkout">Checkout</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank your for your helping its work.
If i want to one more product, perceives it as a single product. How do I add multiple products?

Comment: can you show the view , how do you added multiple product based on that change the code

Comment: i added last post. only first product quantity work. second and others quantity not work.


I think the function "this" is missing

Answer (score 0):

```js
/* Set rates + misc */
var taxRate = 0.18;
var fadeTime = 300;


/* Assign actions */
//$('.product-quantity input').change( function() {
  //updateQuantity(this);
//});

$(document).on('click', '.update-quantity-product', function(e){

  var vals =  $('.product-quantity input').val();
 // alert(vals);
   updateQuantity(vals, $('.product-quantity input'));
})

$('.cpa-delete').click( function() {
  removeItem(this);
});


/* Recalculate cart */
function recalculateCart()
{
  var subtotal = 0;
  
  /* Sum up row totals */
  $('.cpa-product').each(function () {
    subtotal += parseFloat($(this).children('.product-line-price').text());
  });
  
  /* Calculate totals */
  var tax = subtotal * taxRate;
  var total = subtotal + tax;
  
  /* Update totals display */
  $('.totals-value').fadeOut(fadeTime, function() {
    $('#cart-subtotal').html(subtotal.toFixed(2));
    $('#cart-tax').html(tax.toFixed(2));
    $('#cart-total-tax').html(total.toFixed(2));
    $('#cart-total').html(total.toFixed(2));
    if(total == 0){
      $('.checkout').fadeOut(fadeTime);
    }else{
      $('.checkout').fadeIn(fadeTime);
    }
    $('.totals-value').fadeIn(fadeTime);
  });
}


/* Update quantity */
function updateQuantity(qty, quantityInput)
{
  /* Calculate line price */
  var productRow = $(quantityInput).parent().parent();
  var price = parseFloat(productRow.children('.product-price').text());
  var quantity = $(quantityInput).val();
  var linePrice = price * quantity;
  
  /* Update line price display and recalc cart totals */
  productRow.children('.product-line-price').each(function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(fadeTime, function() {
      $(this).text(linePrice.toFixed(2));
      recalculateCart();
      $(this).fadeIn(fadeTime);
    });
  });  
}


/* Remove item from cart */
function removeItem(removeButton)
{
  /* Remove row from DOM and recalc cart total */
  var productRow = $(removeButton).parent().parent();
  productRow.slideUp(fadeTime, function() {
    productRow.remove();
    recalculateCart();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cpa-col row no-gutters align-items-center mt-3 pt-3 cpa-product">
       <div class="col-xl-1 pr-xl-2">
        <a href=""><img src="images/img8.png" class="img-fix d-block cpa-img" alt="" /></a>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xl-5 mt-2 mt-xl-0 text-center text-xl-left pl-xl-2">
        <a class="cpa-name" href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xl-2 mt-2 mt-xl-0 product-quantity number row no-gutters">
        <span class="minus">-</span>
        <input type="text" value="1"/>
        <span class="plus">+</span>
        <button class="update-quantity-product">Güncelle</button>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xl-2 text-center product-price money">
        255.98
       </div>
       <div class="col-xl-1 text-center product-line-price money">
        255.98
       </div>
       <div class="col-xl-1 mt-2 mt-xl-0 text-center text-xl-right">
        <div class="cpa-delete">Sil</div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cpa-col row no-gutters align-items-center mt-3 pt-3 cpa-product">
       <div class="col-xl-1 pr-xl-2">
        <a href=""><img src="images/img8.png" class="img-fix d-block cpa-img" alt="" /></a>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xl-5 mt-2 mt-xl-0 text-center text-xl-left pl-xl-2">
        <a class="cpa-name" href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xl-2 mt-2 mt-xl-0 product-quantity number row no-gutters">
        <span class="minus">-</span>
        <input type="text" value="1"/>
        <span class="plus">+</span>
        <button class="update-quantity-product">Güncelle</button>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xl-2 text-center product-price money">
        255.98
       </div>
       <div class="col-xl-1 text-center product-line-price money">
        255.98
       </div>
       <div class="col-xl-1 mt-2 mt-xl-0 text-center text-xl-right">
        <div class="cpa-delete">Sil</div>
       </div>
      </div>
            
            
            <div class="cpr-content totals">
      <div class="cpr-col mt-3">
       <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-6">Ara Toplam</div>
        <div class="col-6 text-right totals-value money" id="cart-subtotal">255.98</div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cpr-col mt-3">
       <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-6">KDV %18</div>
        <div class="col-6 text-right totals-value money" id="cart-tax">12.75</div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cpr-col mt-3">
       <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-6">KDV Dahil</div>
        <div class="col-6 text-right totals-value money" id="cart-total-tax">268.73</div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cpr-col mt-3">
       <div class="cpr-last pt-3">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
         <div class="col-6">Toplam</div>
         <div class="col-6 text-right totals-value money" id="cart-total">268.73</div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: i didnt get in which way you want to do sum here because its confusing in that post

Comment: Each product is added in "cpa-product".
When more than one product is added, the "quantity" value is calculated only for the first product.
Other products can not be calculated according to the number.

If you want to i can clear this html codes.